# Huge battery power consumption with one particular SIM card

Tags: battery-life, stock-android, sim-card

I have a *Vodafone* SIM card in an Android phone. In that phone, there is a **2000 mAh** battery. I had noticed that the battery was discharging very fast, about **2%/hour when idle**!
At that time, no battery consuming apps were running and all other mobile radios were switched off.
The discharge rate should have been less than **1%/hour**.

I thought that this might be a problem with the battery, but when I tested with another Vodafone SIM card, I saw that the discharge rate has again gone down to 1%/hour!

Can anybody say what is actually happening?

**Additional information**: Few days ago, accidentally, there had been a half-hole on the SIM card. So, is the problem due to this hole?

Comment: How old is the SIM card? The required power voltage of SIM cards has AFAIK changed over the years. Therefore older SIMs need more voltage and usually more power.

Comment: No, that was relatively a newer SIM card.